# Class function that creates an instance of itself in Delphi

Tags: delphi, design-patterns, delphi-xe

Can you have a class function that creates an instance of a class:

```
TMyClass = class(TSomeParent)
public
  class function New(AValue : integer) : TMyClass; 
end;

TDerivedClass = class(TMyClass)
public
  function Beep;
end;
```

and then use it as follows

```
...   
var
  myList : TList<T>;
  item : TDerivedClass;
begin
  myList.Add(TDerivedClass.New(1))
  myList.Add(TDerivedClass.New(3))
  myList.Add(TDerivedClass.New(5))

  for item in myList do
    item.Beep; //times the count in the class function
...
```

And if so, what does that function code look like? Do you use TObject's NewInstance method and do you re-implement every-time for every derived class? Is it saver/better to use the Constructor?

The goal is to use this approach in a command pattern and load the command list with class types and a receiver e.g:

```
//FYI: document is an instance of TDocument
commandList.Execute(TOpenDocument(document)); 
commandList.Execute(TPasteFromClipboard(document)); 
//... lots of actions - some can undo
commandList.Execute(TPrintDocument(document)); 
commandList.Execute(TSaveDocument(document));
```

And the reason for this is that some commands will be specified via text/script and will need to be resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you have a class function that creates an instance of a class. 
>   Is it saver/better to use the Constructor?

Constructor is a class function that creates an instance of class.
Just put:

```
constructor New(); virtual;
```

And you are good to go.

The `virtual;` part will let you call same New() constructor for all descendant classes.

Comment: There's no reason to call the constructor New instead of Create, and there's no reason for it to be virtual.

Comment: @Rob: There is a reason for constructor override when constructing is done via class variables. I agree that Create is, by far, a better name; it is New() here just to relate to question where New() is given as the name of class function.

Comment: It's true that virtual constructors are only useful when class-reference variables are used, but it's *not* true that virtual constructors are *required* for that. You only need virtual constructors if you need to *override* them in descendant classes; it's no different from any other use of virtual methods. The question gave no indication that descendants would need different construction behavior from their base class (aside from constructing a different class, but that's automatic).

Answer (score 13):

What you're looking for is called the *factory pattern*. It can be done in Delphi; it's how the VCL deserializes forms, among other things.  What you're missing is the registration/lookup part of the system.  Here's the basic idea:

- Somewhere, you set up a registration table.  If you're on Delphi XE, you can implement this as a `TDictionary<string, TMyClassType>`, where `TMyClassType` is defined as `class of TMyClass`.  This is important.  You need a map between class names and class type references.
- Put a virtual constructor on TMyClass.  Everything that descends from it will use this constructor, or an override of it, when the factory pattern creates it.
- When you create a new descendant class, have it call a method that will register itself with the registration table.  This should happen at program startup, either in **initialization** or in a class constructor.

When you need to instantiate something from a script, do it like this:

```
 class function TMyClass.New(clsname: string; [other params]): TMyClass;
 begin
   result := RegistrationTable[clsName].Create(other params);
 end;
```

You use the registration table to get the class reference from the class name, and call the virtual constructor on the class reference to get the right type of object out of it.

Comment: Wow. Talk about overengineering a simple problem!

Comment: @Rob: Huh?  This is about the simplest you can make "create objects derived from a base type whose actual type comes from a script" and have it work.

Comment: @Mason: I use `RegisterClass()` and `GetClass()` for now (as the classes are not available if not used in code). The resolution is currently on the class name as the input BUT that's old style, the approach above is on the cards with custom attributes as well, which will result in the class being registered by the RTTI as well when loaded to the dict, no getting away from the registration part + with the dict approach you can have multiple resolution entry points to the command. The question was re the constructor / new issue (and a stupid one really) - thanks for the input on the pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is technically possible to create an instance from a class method, simply call the actual constructor and then return the instance it creates, eg:

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TSomeParent)
  public
    constructor Create(AValue : Integer); virtual;
    class function New(AValue : integer) : TMyClass;
  end;

  TDerivedClass = class(TMyClass)
  public
    constructor Create(AValue : Integer); override;
    function Beep;
  end;

constructor TMyClass.Create(AValue : Integer);
begin
  inherited Create;
  ...
end;

function TMyClass.New(AValue : integer) : TMyClass;
begin
  Result := Create(AValue);
end;

constructor TDerivedClass.Create(AValue : Integer);
begin
  inherited Create(AValue);
  ...
end;

var
  myList : TList<TMyClass>;
  item : TMyClass;
begin
  myList.Add(TDerivedClass.New(1))
  myList.Add(TDerivedClass.New(3))
  myList.Add(TDerivedClass.New(5))
  for item in myList do
    TDerivedClass(item).Beep;
```

In which case, you are better off just using the constructor directly:

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TSomeParent)
  end;

  TDerivedClass = class(TMyClass)
  public
    constructor Create(AValue : Integer);
    function Beep;
  end;

var
  myList : TList<TDerivedClass>;
  item : TDerivedClass;
begin
  myList.Add(TDerivedClass.Create(1))
  myList.Add(TDerivedClass.Create(3))
  myList.Add(TDerivedClass.Create(5))
  for item in myList do
    item.Beep;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use RTTI. The code below runs as a normal method in my class as a way to get a new instance of the object with a subset of items, but as the items (along with the list object itself) are probably of descendent objects, creating an instance of the object in which the method is defined isn't good enough as it needs to be of the same type of the instance.

i.e.

```
TParentItem = Class
End;

TParentList = Class
  Items : TList<TParentItem>;
  Function GetSubRange(nStart,nEnd : Integer) : TParentList;
End;

TChildItem = Class(TParentItem)
end

TChildList = Class(TParentList)
end

List := TChildList.Create;
List.LoadData;

SubList := List.GetSubRange(1,3);
```

The implementation if GetSubRange would be something like...

```
Function TParentList.GetSubRange(nStart,nEnd : Integer) : TParentList;
var
  aContext: TRttiContext;
  aType: TRttiType;
  aInsType : TRttiInstanceType;
  sDebug : String;
begin
  aContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  aType := aContext.GetType(self.ClassType);
  aInsType := aType.AsInstance;
  Result := aInsType.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(aInsType.MetaclassType,[]).AsType<TParentList>;
  sDebug := Result.ClassName; // Should be TChildList

  // Add the items from the list that make up the subrange.
End;
```

I appreciate for some things it may be a bit OTT, but in the design above, it works and is another alternative, although I appreciate, its not a class method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a constructor (a special "kind" of class function). `TObject.NewInstance` is not a suitable option, unless you require special memory allocation.

And regarding the Execute routine of the command list: the action involved now depends on the type of the object. Imagine a document being able to open, print, paste and save at the same time (not a weird assumption), that would be difficult to implement in this structure. Instead, consider to add interfaces (IOpenDocument, IPasteFromClipboard, IPrintable, ISaveDocument) which indeed could all be actions of one document instance.